# z-index and stacking order

Tags: css, z-index

```
<div class="card-body" style="opacity:0.99;"> <!-- stacking context’s root element [![enter image description here][1]][1]-->
  <h5 style="padding-left:60px;position:relative;z-index:10;" class="card-title"><!-- stacking order: 1 -->
    <i style="position:absolute;font-size:60px;color:red;top:-10px;left:-10px;" class="fa fa-play-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Video Title
  </h5>
  <div class="card-details-1 clearfix" style="position:relative;z-index:20;"><!-- stacking order: 2 -->
    <div>
      <span class="card-date float-left">19.02.17</span>
      <a class="card-username float-right" href="#">Username</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-details-2 clearfix">
    <div>
      <span class="card-duration float-left">7:56 min</span>
      <span class="card-votes float-right">20 Votes</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="card-btn" href="#">View Video</a>
</div>
```

1. I have applied an opacity value less than 1 to the `div.card-body` in order to form a new stacking context.
2. `h5` and `div.card-details-1` are positioned and have a z-index value.

Why I can't get the black-colored effect shown in the picture?

[image]

Comment: what picture are you referring to? you should post your css and arrange a complete and minimal example

Comment: `card-body` needs to be positioned as well #

Comment: Sorry for the missing picture. The link to the picture is now live. The black-colored drawing shows the desired effect. Numbers indicate the stacking order.

Comment: Could you add css styles?